# inner product zero?

Tags: fourier-series

I am studying about Fourier series from book"Signals and
Systems Laboratory with MATLAB"

I came across topic "Orthogonality of Complex Exponential Signals"

I am confused in case when m=k, will the two signals still orthogonal in this case ?(highlighted yellow)

[image]

Comment: When m=k, the two signals are the same signal. They cannot be orthogonal to themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, when $m=k$ the integral is:
$$
\int_0^T e^{j(m-k)\Omega_0t} dt = 
\int_0^T e^{j \cdot 0 \cdot\Omega_0t}  dt = \int_0^T  dt = T
$$

So as Juancho says in the comments,  it's the same signal and so can't be orthogonal to itself.

Answer (score 3):

The text is a bit cumbersome, in that it states "things" before defining them. And the zero-signal (or vector) is considered orthogonal to every other vector. This is why the sentence "If $I=0$ for..." seems unnecessarily complicated to me. And the $m$ and $k$ indices introduced at the beginning come out of nowhere until we understand they are integer complex exponential indices. Moreover, introducing $x$ and $y$ at the very end is quite inconsistent with the previous $x_m$ and $x_k$ notations.

In a mood for conciseness and precision, let me rewrite the text (with missing hypotheses, like $\Omega_{0}\neq 0 $), hoping it will be more direct.

> Let us consider in the following complex-valued continuous-time
>   periodic signals with period $T>0$. The inner product of $x_1$ and
>   $x_2$ is defined as:
>
> $$I(x_1,x_2)=\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{0}+T} x_1(t) x_2^{*}(t) d t$$
>
> where $x^{*}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $x$. Two signals are
>   orthogonal if their inner product is zero. Suppose now that $(m,k)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$, $\Omega_{0}\neq 0 $
>    and define $x_{1}(t)=e^{j m \Omega_{0} t}$ and
>   $x_{2}(t)=e^{j k \Omega_{0} t}$. Since:  $$I(x_1,x_2)=\int_{0}^{T}
>  e^{j m \Omega_{0} t_{e}-j k \Omega_{0} t} d t=\int_{0}^{T} e^{j(m-k)
>  \Omega_{0} t} d t=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{T,} & {k=m} \\ {0,} & {k
>  \neq m}\end{array}\right.\,,$$ then the complex exponentials $e^{j m \Omega_{0} t}$ and  $e^{j k \Omega_{0} t}$ are
>   orthogonal if $m\neq k$.